# Integrate Twilio PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio, twilio-api

My Twilio PHP, my HTML form are working well in local but when I put files in my Wordpress theme folder and try to include the PHP file by adding this line of code in header.php before  tags :

```
<?php include 'sendnotifications.php';?>
```

I have this error on my page:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'sendnotifications.php' for
 inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.1') in 
/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php on line 3
```

edit:

It's working, I didn't place files in good folder. Now I have an other issue, it is only working with predifined phone numbers:

```
$sid = 'MySID';
$token = 'MyToken';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

    // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
    $client->messages->create(
        // the number you'd like to send the message to
       'MyPersonal number',  
        array(
            // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
            'from' => 'MyTwilioNumber',
            // the body of the text message you'd like to send
            'body' => 'Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!'
```

But when I try to get custom phone number from a form on my page :

```
$sid = 'MySID';
$token = 'MyToken';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$phone=$_POST["phone"];

            // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
            $client->messages->create(
                // the number you'd like to send the message to
               $phone,  
                array(
                    // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
                    'from' => 'MyTwilioNumber',
                    // the body of the text message you'd like to send
                    'body' => 'Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!'
```

I have this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: A 'To' phone number is required. in /homepages/10/d659162273/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php:85 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/10/d659162273/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php(219): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...') #1 /homepages/10/d659162273/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageList.php(69): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Accounts/AC8ec...', Array, Array) #2 /homepages/10/d659162273/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/sendnotifications.php(20): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList->create(NULL, Object(Twilio\Values)) #3 /homepages/10/d659162273/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php(3): include('/homepag in /homepages/10/d659162273/htdocs/clickandbuilds/MyWebsite/wp-content/themes/Divi/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php on line 85
```

I'm a little bit lost

Comment: Are you definitely retrieving the phone number from the body of the POST request correctly? What is the name attribute of the `<input>` on the page you request the phone number?

Answer (score 3):

You should install the twilio plugin for wordpress to get it worked with wordpress.

Here is the plugin link to [download](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-twilio-core/). After that you will have to write your code.

Follow the official tutorial of twilio for wordpress on below link:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/send-sms-wordpress-php-plugin.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: Its permission issue in twilio, You'll have to login to your twilio account and navigate to voice calls (geo permissions) settings and check the countries to which you are making calls, then save.